# Including jquery UI in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have tried to get jquery-ui working with wordpress with no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction? I've dug up a ton of SO resources and blogs explaining it, but so far can't get this working. However when I include the scripts directly in the page itself I can get the datepicker to function properly. I'm trying to make the table rows draggable (and eventually droppable).

Here is what I currently have-

In /themes/twentysixteen/functions.php

I followed the steps here and enqueued jquery-ui functions [Correctly enqueue jquery-ui](http://xl-websites.com/how-to-enqueue-jquery-or-jquery-ui-correctly-in-wordpress/). I then added a couple of my own scripts based on the information here [Add jquery scripts](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/?nhtz=b&utm_expid=3606929-91.15T0nlf8TFCqo1W_BlZjGg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

```html
/* Used to include jquery-ui scripts
*  Taken from http://xl-websites.com/how-to-enqueue-jquery-or-jquery-ui-correctly-in-wordpress/
*
*/

function add_jquery_ui() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-droppable');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-resize');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-button');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jquery_ui' );

function custom_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script('date', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/date.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('drag', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/drag.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_js');
```

With those addded, I created the scripts in my js folder-

/js/drag.js

```html
(function() {
        $(".drag").draggable({
                helper: function(event) {
                        return $('<div class="drag-row"><table></table></div>').find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone()).end();
                },
        });
});
```

And /js/date.js

```html
( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

In my php page I added the date id to a calendar, and a class id to the table row as targets for the jquery scripts.

```html
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

        echo "<div id='table'>";
        echo "<table class='listing'>";
                echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th><b>Course Name</b></th>";
                                echo "<th><b>Fiscal Year</b></th>";
                                echo "<th><b>Course Number</b></th>";
                                echo "<th><b>Start Date</b></th>";
                                echo "<th><b>End Date</b></th>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                        foreach($courses as $course){
                                echo "<tr class='drag'>";
                                        echo "<td>".$course->course_name."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$course->fy."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$course->course_number."</td>";

                                        $date = $course->course_date_start;
                                        $date = strtotime($date);

                                        if ($date){
                                                echo "<td>".date("m/d/Y", $date)."</td>";
                                        } else {
                                                echo "<td></td>";
                                        }

                                        $date = $course->course_date_end;
                                        $date = strtotime($date);

                                        if ($date){
                                                echo "<td>".date("m/d/Y", $date)."</td>";
                                        } else {
                                                echo "<td></td>";                                               }
                                        echo "</tr>";
                        }
                echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
```

When my page loads, the scripts are all there (including jquery, I put spaces since the jquery lines are at line 350, and the jquery-ui lines are at line 500), but the ui isn't functional. Anyone have any insights?

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>




<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/functions.js?ver=20160816'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/accordion.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/position.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/wp-a11y.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var uiAutocompleteL10n = {"noResults":"No search results.","oneResult":"1 result found. Use up and down arrow keys to navigate.","manyResults":"%d results found. Use up and down arrow keys to navigate."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/tabs.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/sortable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/draggable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/droppable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({"closeText":"Close","currentText":"Today","monthNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"monthNamesShort":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],"nextText":"Next","prevText":"Previous","dayNames":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"dayNamesShort":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"dayNamesMin":["S","M","T","W","T","F","S"],"dateFormat":"MM d, yy","firstDay":1,"isRTL":false});});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/resizable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/button.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/dialog.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/date.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/drag.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='##/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
```

Comment: What's the `##/` in front of the URL, just skipped the domain or...?

Comment: jquery draggable included in wordpress admin not for frontend.

Comment: Yes, I scrubbed the domain out and replaced it with #

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the `wp_enqueue_script()` function that your scripts **depend on jQuery**, so they will be inserted in correct way and order, notice the third parameter, for example:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core', false, array('jquery'));
```

Read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Also note that `jQuery UI Effects` is not included with the `jquery-ui-core` handle.

Comment: My understanding was the jquery dependency was handled for the ui scripts since ui comes with word press. Is the example I took the jquery-ui inclusion from incorrect then? I specified jquery was a dependency for my custom scripts

Comment: Specify the opposite: your scripts depend on jQuery.

Comment: I specified that in the custom_js function in functions.js: wp_enqueue_script('date', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/date.js', array('jquery'), false, true);

Comment: Applied to the enqueue_script for the jquery ui core line, that didn't work